# Why does this webrtc streamer only work on local connections?

Tags: javascript, c++, webrtc

The streamer only seems to work if both peers are on the same machine or the same local network. The only way I've gotten it to work over the internet is by connecting my desktop to my google cloud vm with openvpn.  chrome://webrtc-internals/ shows that iconnectionstatechange is failed but I don't know enough about webrtc to interpret that.

I thought the problem was that stun servers weren't being used so I added stun:stun.l.google.com:19302 to the peer connection config in both [webrtc_client.cpp](https://github.com/pbafff/webrtc_ros/blob/fe1262ba385d21bbe673f138d6a4e1301d41ebcc/webrtc_ros/src/webrtc_client.cpp#L117) and [webrtc_ros.js](https://github.com/pbafff/webrtc_ros/blob/fe1262ba385d21bbe673f138d6a4e1301d41ebcc/webrtc_ros/web/webrtc_ros.js#L16) in my fork but no luck.

Comment: Have you tried removing the non-standard `DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement` and leave the candidates alone (serialize them as-is, instead of trying to translate them to a different format and back?)

Comment: My problem seems to be that the webrtc_ros streamer is only generating host ice candidates for some reason.